# how do i show a div on clicking another div and hide it on clicking that same div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have a div with 7 children, on hover an item changes background and text pads left from center. I've done that with CSS.
now i want when the user clicks on an item it shows another div (.wrapper) with JavaScript. if the user click again it hides the particular div.
how can i achieve this logic with JavaScript?

here is my html snippet

```
<div class="category">
    <div class="furniture">Furniture</div>
    <div class="tableware">Tableware</div>
    <div class="jewellery">Jewellery</div>
    <div class="shoes">Shoes</div>
    <div class="water_bottles">Water Bottles</div>
    <div class="clothes">Clothes</div>
    <div class="textiles">Fabric Patterns</div>
</div>

<div class="upload">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="control"><img src="back.png"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="content_desc"></div>
            <div class="control"><img src="forward.png"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS code

```
/*styles individual divs in the category class*/
.category > div:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform-style: flat;
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px 1px 1px 1px solid;
    background-color: #898488;
    color: #7AC4EE;
    border-left-color: yellow;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
/*class that i want to display on click*/
.wrapper {
    display: none;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 623px;
    padding: 0;
    align-self: center;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    box-shadow:  0px 3px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
/*the classes below are in .wrapper*/
.control {
   flex: 1;  
   background:white; 
   position: relative;
}

.content {
   flex: 4;
   height: 92%;
   width: 415px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   background: lightblue;
   position: relative;
}
.content_desc {
   flex: 2;
   height: 22px;
   width: 415px;
   margin-top: 370px ;
   margin-left: 104px;
   margin-right: 98.5px;
   background-color: white;
   border: 0.3px solid;
   position: absolute;
}

.control img {
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
   background: white;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.control img:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
   background-color: yellow;
   transition-delay: 0.2s;
   animation: 0.1s ease-in;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.category' > div ).on('click', function(){
  $('.wrapper').show();
  })
});
```

Comment: did you try ".toggle" instead of ".show" ?
so that when you click it will hide if shown, and show it if hidden

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use this code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.category>div' ).on('click', function(){
     $('.wrapper').toggle();
      })
    });
```

and add this css to hide div in starting

```
.wrapper{
display:none
}
```

Comment: .wrapper is on display: none, i've made the changes but it is not responding yet...

Comment: it works just like @Mamun's abave , its an error in my linking the libraries, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the term *particular div* here. May be you can try with `toggle()`. You also have syntax error in wrapping the selector:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.category > div').on('click', function(){
    $('.wrapper').toggle();
  })
});
```

```css
/*styles individual divs in the category class*/
.category > div:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform-style: flat;
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px 1px 1px 1px solid;
    background-color: #898488;
    color: #7AC4EE;
    border-left-color: yellow;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
/*class that i want to display on click*/
.wrapper {
    display: none;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 623px;
    padding: 0;
    align-self: center;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    box-shadow:  0px 3px 7px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
/*the classes below are in .wrapper*/
.control {
   flex: 1;  
   background:white; 
   position: relative;
}

.content {
   flex: 4;
   height: 92%;
   width: 415px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   background: lightblue;
   position: relative;
}
.content_desc {
   flex: 2;
   height: 22px;
   width: 415px;
   margin-top: 370px ;
   margin-left: 104px;
   margin-right: 98.5px;
   background-color: white;
   border: 0.3px solid;
   position: absolute;
}

.control img {
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
   background: white;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.control img:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
   background-color: yellow;
   transition-delay: 0.2s;
   animation: 0.1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="category">
    <div class="furniture">Furniture</div>
    <div class="tableware">Tableware</div>
    <div class="jewellery">Jewellery</div>
    <div class="shoes">Shoes</div>
    <div class="water_bottles">Water Bottles</div>
    <div class="clothes">Clothes</div>
    <div class="textiles">Fabric Patterns</div>
</div>

<div class="upload">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="control"><img src="back.png"></div>
            <div class="content"></div>
            <div class="content_desc"></div>
            <div class="control"><img src="forward.png"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The .wrapper is the div to be made visible on clicking  eg .furniture a child of category and hidden on clicking that same child.

Comment: what might be wrong with my code ? could it be my referencing of the scripts?                   <body>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>                                       
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">  
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script><header> @mamun

Comment: @molten-lead, yes path of jQuery might not be correct. In that case you should get error in console....

Comment: i have another queston, i wanted the .wrapper to be hidden when the page loads but it shows instead. if i remove the display: flex; in .wrapper CSS it does this but the objects disarrange when i click to show

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake in your css selector, it's not `'.category' > div`, it should be `'.category > div'`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.category > div').on('click', function(){
    $('.wrapper').toggle();
  })
});
```

Comment: still does not work despite, the toggle() and '.category > div'

Comment: I don't how this will meet the condition *if the user click again it hides the particular div*